# Python convert 3 lists to list of dictionaries with list name as key name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists that I would like to convert to a list of dictionaries.  The desired output would be to have the name of the list as the key in each dict.

```
# 3 lists
source_ip_address = ["172.30.1.1","123.123.1.1","180.104.1.1"]
destination_ip_address = ["172.31.1.1","172.31.1.1","192.168.1.1"]
incident_name = ["Credential Sharing","Remote IP","OTP Failures"]


# desired output
[
    {
    'source_ip_address': '172.30.1.1', 
    'destination_ip_address': '172.31.1.1',
    'incident_name': 'Credential Sharing'
    },
    {
    'source_ip_address': '123.123.1.1', 
    'destination_ip_address': '172.31.1.1',
    'incident_name': 'Remote IP'
    },
    {
    'source_ip_address': '180.104.1.1', 
    'destination_ip_address': '192.168.1.1',
    'incident_name': 'OTP Failures'
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you write the code to create one of the dictionaries, given one element each from the lists? Can you write code to iterate over multiple lists in parallel? If you can do both, then what exactly is the difficulty? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try zip and extract?

Comment: Please note that if you are using zip, you need to ensure that the length of all 3 lists are the same. Otherwise, it will iterate thru the zip for n times where n is the min of length of all 3 lists. Let's say, list1 has 3 items, list2 has 2 items, and list3 has 5 items. Then zip will only produce 2 sets and ignore the others as it cannot get the values for the next set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that it or do are you looking for some kind of automation to extract the variable's aliases ?

```
source_ip_address = ["172.30.1.1","123.123.1.1","180.104.1.1"]
destination_ip_address = ["172.31.1.1","172.31.1.1","192.168.1.1"]
incident_name = ["Credential Sharing","Remote IP","OTP Failures"]


print([{'source_ip_address':x, 'destination_ip_address':y, 'incident_name':z} for x,y,z in zip(source_ip_address, destination_ip_address, incident_name)])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to do this but here is what I would do.

```py
result = [{'source_ip_address': source,
           'destination_ip_address': dest,
           'incident_name': incident}
           for source, dest, incident in zip(source_ip_address,
                                             destination_ip_address,
                                             incident_name)]
```

You can do whatever spacing you want, of course, this is just what I thought of first. So I'll quickly explain what it means. So the zip basically just takes each of the lists and turns them into an iterable of tuples of the elements. What that means is that the first element is `('172.30.1.1','172.31.1.1','Credential Sharing')`. The for loops through all of the elements and breaks them up into the separate bits. So in the first iteration, `source='172.30.1.1'`, `dest='172.31.1.1'`, and `incident='Credential Sharing'`. I think it's pretty clear how the dictionary gets built from one iteration. The for is inside of a list comprehension so it runs through all of the elements and produces a list with each of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension or a simple for loop with zip.

```
source_ip_address = ["172.30.1.1","123.123.1.1","180.104.1.1"]
destination_ip_address = ["172.31.1.1","172.31.1.1","192.168.1.1"]
incident_name = ["Credential Sharing","Remote IP","OTP Failures"]

ip_list = []
for a,b,c in zip(source_ip_address,destination_ip_address,incident_name):
    ip_list.append({'source_ip_address':a,
                          'destination_ip_address': b,
                          'incident_name': c})

print (ip_list)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[{'source_ip_address': '172.30.1.1', 'destination_ip_address': '172.31.1.1', 'incident_name': 'Credential Sharing'}, {'source_ip_address': '123.123.1.1', 'destination_ip_address': '172.31.1.1', 'incident_name': 'Remote IP'}, {'source_ip_address': '180.104.1.1', 'destination_ip_address': '192.168.1.1', 'incident_name': 'OTP Failures'}]
```

Just in case you are not familiar with zip and want to use a regular iteration, you can do something like this as well.

```
n = len(source_ip_address)
ip_list = []

for i in range(n):
    ip_list.append({'source_ip_address':source_ip_address[i],
                          'destination_ip_address': destination_ip_address[i],
                          'incident_name': incident_name[i]})

print (ip_list)
```

Output of this will also be the same.